# iOS: Unbalanced calls to begin/end appearance transitions for MasterViewController on iPhone

Tags: ios, uitabbarcontroller, uisplitviewcontroller

I have UITabBarController as a root view controller. In one of the tab bar items I have UIViewController with container with embedded UISplitViewController. Master and detail view controllers are embedded in UINavigationController.

I get "Unbalanced calls to begin/end appearance transitions for" error when I am in some tab bar item (which does not have split view controller) in landscape orientation and I rotate to the portrait and I have selected earlier some item in the master view controller, so both master and detail view controller are visible (in landscape only).

I know it happens because when I rotate the split view controller delegate method 
`splitViewController:collapseSecondaryViewController:ontoPrimaryViewController:` is called and try to push detail view controller on the stack but what can I do to fix this?

Comment: you need to provide more code, so people can help you

Comment: @Basheer_CAD I am not sure what to provide, because everything is set in the storyboard and in the code I override only trait collection to show split view on the iPhone in landscape orientation. Except that nothing special happens in the code.